# Installing a distro on an external hard drive without adding a bootloader to my internal drive

Tags: software-installation

I want to install a distro on my external drive but do not want to add any bootloader to my internal drive.
Is it possible to install it in such a way that when I plug in said external drive, it will show up in my bootmenu as a bootlable drive just like a usb bootable installation media thing?
Please help with a beginner friendly solution. (I've installed a few distros (debian, arch) and spent some time with the command line as well) (The distro I want to install right now is archlabs.)

Comment: Yes, it's possible and AFAIK only Ubuntu's installer in UEFI mode doesn't respect the users selection for the (EFI) bootloader installation and always installs in the first drive's ESP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto can you elaborate on how to do this? Because when I tried to install zorins bootloader on the external drive, it was not bootable.

Comment: Zorin is based on Ubuntu so probably has the same issue. One easy way to  workaround the problem is to disconnect or temporarily disable the internal drives.